# How to integrate JMeter Docker with Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure, docker, jmeter, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a requirement in which i have to run JMeter test using docker images in azure pipelines.Is there any way in which this can be accomplished.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, how the things going? Does the container job could help you achieve what you want? If yes, you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works. If you still facing any issues, feel free to leave commend here :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Run JMeter test using docker images in azure pipelines

In azure pipeline, we offer a approach [Container jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) which would help you achieve this. We provided the docker image for the agents which can make it easily to run them as containers. Then you will be able to run your Jmeter test steps inside that container.

If you hosted the image in Docker Hub, just specify the `image name` and the corresponding `tag` to the parameter `container` in YAML:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-16.04'

container: ubuntu:16.04

steps:
..
..
..
```

Then, the pipeline server will fetch the corresponding image from Docker Hub, then start the container to run the steps, such as run Jmeter test task.

The script is for when the image is hosted in the Docker hub. If you want to fetch the image from Azure Container Registry, you should specify the **service connection endpoint** in YAML:

```
container:
  image: myprivate/registry:ubuntu1604
  endpoint: private_dockerhub_connection
```

***Note:*** Until now, the `container job` are only available for `YAML`.

For detailed step, you can track these two blogs and our official doc: [Containerized build pipeline](https://mobilefirstcloudfirst.net/2018/10/containerized-build-pipeline-azure-devops/), [run private agents as docker containers](https://mohitgoyal.co/2019/01/05/running-azure-devops-private-agents-as-docker-containers/) and [Using containerized services](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/using-containerized-services-in-your-pipeline/).

Hope this approach could help you achieve run Jmeter test with Docker image.